# How to query Angularjs directive nested DOM element by a dynamic selector?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive, angular-template, angular-directive-link

Directive allocation inside a parent template:

```
<div badge></div>
```

Directive template `templates/badge.html`:
*Notice allocation of the dynamic id, using directive `$id`.*

```
<div>
    <span id="id{{ ::$id }}_name">Nik Sumeiko, Frontend engineer</span>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('badge', () => ({
  restrict: "A",
  replace: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/badge.html",
  link: (scope, element, attributes) => {

    // Tries to query nested DOM element by a dynamic selector.
    const name = element.find(`#id${scope.$id}_name`);

    console.log(name.length, element.html());
  }
}));
```

Based on the console output it's clearly visible that directive template haven't compiled its dynamic values yet:

```
0 "
    <div>
      <span id="id{{ ::$id }}_name">Nik Sumeiko, Frontend engineer</span>
    </div>
"
```

**How then it is possible to query nested elements by a dynamic selector?** Is there any other directive methods that are dispatched after Angular rendered dynamic values of the template?

*Please don't suggest to use `$timeout` injected function to delay template rendering inside `link` method, since I don't think it is the right way…*

Answer (score 2):

Here the quote from angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile):

> After linking the view is not updated until after a call to $digest which typically is done by Angular automatically.

That's why you can't find the elements containing expressions in their id - the view is not updated at that time.

Here the workarounds:

**Create the element and attach it to the DOM manually**

This way you have a reference to element, so you don't have to query for it:

```
link: (scope, element, attributes) => {
    let span = $compile('<span id="id{{ ::$id }}_name">Nik Sumeiko, Frontend engineer</span>')(scope);
    // do something to span ...
    element.append(span);
}
```

**Use $timeout**

You can use `$timeout` with a zero delay, it is not the wrong way. `$timeout` will execute your code right after the current `$digest` cycle, meaning after the view bindings are updated:

```
link: (scope, element, attributes) => {
    $timeout(function() {
        let span = element[0].querySelector(`#id${scope.$id}_name`);
    });
}
```